# Pandas group if variable can be arranged in consecutive order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of the following form.

```
  id  year
0  A  2000
1  A  2001
2  B  2005
3  B  2006
4  B  2007
5  C  2003
6  C  2004
7  D  2002
8  D  2003
```

Now two or more IDs are assumed to be part of an aggregated ID if they can be arranged in a consecutive order. Meaning that in the end I would like to have this grouping, in which A & D build a group and B & C another one:

```
  id  year  match
0  A  2000   1 
1  A  2001   1
7  D  2002   1
8  D  2003   1

5  C  2003   2
6  C  2004   2
2  B  2005   2
3  B  2006   2
4  B  2007   2
```

EDIT: Addressing @Dimitris_ps comments: Assuming an additional row

```
  id  year
9  A  2002
```

would change the desired result to

```
  id  year  match
0  A  2000   1 
1  A  2001   1
9  A  2002   1
5  C  2003   1
6  C  2004   1
2  B  2005   1
3  B  2006   1
4  B  2007   1

7  D  2002   2
8  D  2003   2
```

because now there is no longer a consecutive order for A & D but instead for A, C, and B with D having no match.

Comment: What happens if you also had another row with id:A and year 2002, how should the end result be? You need to give more details for more and different cases

Comment: There are no cases in which two or more IDs can form a consecutive order with another ID. In the case of another row with id: A and year 2002, A, C, and B would form a group and D would have no match

Answer (score 0):

Recode your `id` to values and then you can sort based on `year` and `id`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D'], 
'year':[2000, 2001, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2003, 2004, 2002, 2003]}) # example dataframe

# Create a dict mapping id to values based on the minimum year
custom_dict = {el:i for i, el in enumerate(df.groupby('id')['year'].min().sort_values().index)}

# and the reverse to map back the values to the id
custom_dict_rev = {v:k for k, v in custom_dict.items()}

df['id'] = df['id'].map(custom_dict) 


df = df.sort_values(['year', 'id'])
df['id'] = df['id'].map(custom_dict_rev)

df
```

Comment: While this works for the example I provided, it no longer work when adding another row with id:A and year 2002 as mentioned in your comment to the original post.

Comment: can you specify in your question what the expected solution should be when you gave this extra row